# What do the buttons on a Comelit Okay Simplebus2 Intercom/door entry system do?

Tags: electrical, doors

I've got a Comelit Okay Simplebus2 door entry system which yesterday wasn't able to be used to let someone into the building, however I'm not sure if the buttons next to the phone were being used correctly.

The interface has 2 buttons, 1 with a key and 1 with a lightbulb symbol, and I'm wondering if anyone has seen this style before and knows how it should be used?

[image]

I've tried calling the manufacturer but like most places the phone line's closed at weekends

Comment: One of the better ways to answer this sort of question is to check whether the manufacturer's manuals are on line....

Answer (score -1):

It can be configured to turn on an external light

Comment: Please improve this answer by explaining **how**.